# Use AutoMapper to use map of derived object instead of parent object

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper

I can't figure a solution to my problem using AutoMapper nor find right keywords to find a solution online, hence the maybe bad title for that question, here is my problem:

I'd like to force AutoMapper to use one map out of two valid maps. Here an exemple:

```
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class ADTO
{
    public BDTO B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
}

public class BDTO
{
}

public class CDTO : BDTO
{
}

public class AProfile : Profile
{
    public AProfile()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<B, BDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<B, CDTO>();

        // Is there a way to force AutoMapper to use B to CDTO instead of B to BDTO ?
        Mapper.CreateMap<A, ADTO>()
            .ForMember(adto => adto.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.B));
    }
}
```

If I remove below line, AutoMapper throws an error saying that it can't find a valid map for B property in A to ADTO map.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<B, BDTO>();
```

Is there any way to make my map B to CDTO valid for it ?

**EDIT from Lucian answer**

So I guess one solution is to make it two steps :

```
var a = new A { B = new B() }
var adto = new ADTO();

adto = Mapper.Map(a, adto); // Map B to BDTO
adto.B = Mapper.Map<CDTO>(a.B); // Change BDTO to CDTO
```

I'm more into one proper line solution :

```
var a = new A { B = new B() }
var adto = new ADTO();

adto = Mapper.Map(a, adto); // Map directly B to CDTO
```

Any way to make it happen ?

**EDIT 2 from Lucian answer again**

The fact is that A and B are entities coming from EF and that I don't have access to ADTO initialization as I use .ProjectTo extension.

My code is something more like:

```
var adto = db.As.ProjectTo<ADTO>().ToList();
```

Where `db` is my `DbContext` and `As` my `DbSet` of `A`.

**EDIT 3 from Lucian answer again**

I did not know about that ConstructProjectionUsing method, thanks for that! Here the code I manage to build with your answer.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, ADTO>()
   .ConstructProjectionUsing(a => new ADTO() { B = new CDTO() })
   .ForMember(adto => adto.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.B));
```

And that's brillant! But now, I have another problem, B and BDTO are in fact ICollection and IEnumerable... I didn't think it will be a problem so I didn't tell. Here the updated code:

```
public class A
{
    public ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class ADTO
{
    public IEnumerable<BDTO> B { get; set; }
}
```

So I think I can't use the ConstructProjectionUsing as this code won't compile:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, ADTO>()
   .ConstructProjectionUsing(a => new ADTO() { B = new List<CDTO>() }) // Error here, can't convert List<CDTO> to List<BDTO> 
   .ForMember(adto => adto.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.B));
```

I guess I'm stuck here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so As is what allows you to redirect the map. And it seems to work with ProjectTo. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/IntegrationTests/Inheritance/ProjectToAbstractType.cs).

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<B, BDTO>().As<CDTO>();
```

Of course this applies everywhere, not only for ProjectTo.

Comment: That's it, work like a charm. Truly thank you Lucian.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize ADTO.B with an instance of CDTO and map to an existing object.

```
var a = new A { B = new B() };  
var adto = new ADTO { B = new CDTO() };  
Mapper.Map(a, adto); // Map directly B to CDTO
```

This would work with a newer AM. You might need UseDestinationValue with older ones.

Comment: Thank for the answer, I updated my post with your suggestion.

Comment: Well might actually work with this scenario, but I don't have access to ADTO initialization as I use .ProjectTo extension method.
A and B are entities coming from EF.
Let me update my post again.

Answer (score 1):

For construction you can use ConstructProjectionUsing. [An example](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/Projection/ConstructorTests.cs). But otherwise, I think you need the right type in the destination.

Comment: Well, again you provide a correct answer for the problem I exposed and again, that is not working for my real scenario... Let me update my post, again.